# Viewport gizmo buttons not visible on Macbook pro (Blender 2.80)

Tags: 3d-view

I downloaded the latest Blender (2.80) today for my Windows computer aswel as for my Macbook Pro. On the Macbook the Gizmo to rotate the viewport is visible but not the 4 buttons left to it (perspective, camera, move and zoom). If I toggle the "Navigate" checkbox in the viewport gizmos options from the menu above on my windows machine then all 5 buttons appear/disappear, but on the Macbook only the rotate button appears/disappears. Is there perhaps another setting iI have to check somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Strange, activating navigate should also bring all the other options as well. I don't have a mac so I can't test this unfortunately.